# What does this macro return and how do use it?

Tags: c, struct, macros

I have a problem to understand how I can use this macro to get the lenght of the IP header. I have a file called framehdr.h and I have included that file in my main.c. The struct in the framehdr.h file look like this:

```
struct ip_hdr {
    unsigned char vhl;     /* Version and header length */
    unsigned char tos;     /* Type of service */
    unsigned short len;    /* Total length */
    unsigned short id;     /* Identification */
    unsigned short off;    /* Fragment offset field */
    unsigned char ttl;     /* Time to live */
    unsigned char p;       /* Protocol */
    unsigned short ip_sum; /* Checksum */
    unsigned int src, dst; /* Source and dest address */
};
```

I can manually get the lentgh by adding all the sizes like this:

```
unsigned int sizeIP = sizeof(testOne.vhl) + sizeof(testOne.tos)    +
                      sizeof(testOne.len) + sizeof(testOne.id)     + 
                      sizeof(testOne.off) + sizeof(testOne.ttl)    + 
                      sizeof(testOne.p)   + sizeof(testOne.ip_sum) +
                      sizeof(testOne.src) + sizeof(testOne.dst);
```

But I'm suppose to use the macro that look like this to get the size:

```
#define IP_HL(ip) ((((ip)->vhl) & 0x0f) * 4)
```

What does this macro return? Is it a digit so I can store it in a int and then print it or how does it work?

Comment: Since when a MACRO `return`s anything?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Okay does it not return anything? How do I use it then? Can you maybe give me a tip of any material I can read up on this subject?

Comment: `int header_length = IP_HL(pointer_to_struct);`

Comment: Macro invocations are *replaced* by the preprocessor. If you have e.g. `IP_HL(x)` then that will be replaced by `((((x)->vhl) & 0x0f) * 4)`.

Comment: @mch okay will try that! But I tried that before so must have done something wrong then. I'll get back when I tried it

Comment: A macro does not return anything, but in this case, it evaluates to an `int`.

Comment: Also note that [the size of  a `struct` might not be the same as the sum of the size of all its members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah I have already noticed that but we are suppose to use this macro. But thanks for the notice

Comment: @mch If I have a created a struct ip_hdr testOne in the main.c file. Can I make it a pointer by using the &testOne and give it to the IP_HL() macro or do I need to create a new pointer and point it to the testOne since the testOne is where I read in the values from a file to?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `vhl` (which is an 8 bit member, unless CHAR_BIT is a weird value on your platform) is used to store the version in the significant 4 bits and the header length in the other 4 bits.

`((ip)->vhl) & 0x0f)` extracts the least significant 4 bits of the `vhl` member of the `struct` to which `ip` is pointing.

The multiplication by 4 to get the actual length is merely obeying the conventions of that member.

The way you are using `sizeof` to "manually get the length" is making assumptions about the header length corresponding to the sum of the sizes of the individual members. Member *padding* and undocumented conventions centred around the serialisation technique used for your `struct` might mean this is not the case.

Comment: Given the name of the struct, this is probably ipv4. And, [well](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc791#page-11), "*Internet Header Length is the length of the internet header in 32 bit words*", thus probably the `* 4`.